# Запись телефонного разговора в Android

Tags: android, звукозапись

Доброго времени суток, Хэшкод!
Возникла необходимость в собственном простом диктофоне, умеющем писать телефонный разговор. Делаю так:

```
MediaRecorder mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();  
Recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);  // если заменить VOICE_CALL на MIC то звук без проблем пишется с микрофона, прим. К.О. :)  
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR);  
mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);  
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);  
try {  
                mRecorder.prepare();  
            } catch (IOException e) {
                }  
mRecorder.start();
```

В итоге получается файл весом 6 байт, который явно не содержит запись разговора.
На аналогичном Хэшкоду сайте одни рекомендуют использовать приведенный выше код, другие уверяют что запись телефонного разговора невозможна в Android в принципе. Прошу помощи с приведенным выше кодом и/или также подтверждения/опровержения того, что запись беседы невозможна. Спасибо за внимание

Comment: Насколько я догадываюсь, это сильно зависит от прошивки. На MIUI это возможно. Но это так же зависит от конкретных устройств. Присоединяюсь к вопросу.

Comment: вероятней всего ты тут уже был http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194342/how-can-i-record-voice-and-record-call-in-android, там приблизительно так и написано, что надо рутированый доступ или прошивку или китайский телефон или апи он производителя... =)

Comment: Да, но зачем тогда в штатном API сделали AudioSource.VOICE_CALL ? Бесить разработчика?) Дескать, вот вам посылка, но я ее вам не отдам(с)

Comment: Я думаю, чтобы система была полной. Запись разговора - это достаточно скользкая тема для производителей с юридической стороны - нельзя записывать разговор без согласия во многих странах, а производителям разборки в судах не к чему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Со всей ответственностью заявляю, что без хака это невозможно. Об этом говорит feature request, который висит в Google уже давно безо всякой надежды на его реализацию. [Фтыкать сюда](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2117#c226)

С другой стороны на рынке есть [некоторые приложения](http://clevermobile.net/products/call-recorder/call-recorder-list-of-non-supported-devices/), которые позволяют это делать, но опять же с большими ограничениями. Все реализации написаны на основе хака  радиомодулей некоторых известных кристаллов.

**Update**
Запись собственного голоса возможна - доступ к микрофону есть, а вот голос собеседника закрыт.

Comment: В итоге приведенный выше код прекрасно пишет голос обоих собеседников на I9001 и lg p500 . Оба аппарата с родными прошивками но рутованные(правда при запуске приложения ни слова о том, что ему предоставлены права super-user`a). Я в еще большей растерянности )

Comment: Оба аппарата используют чип Qualcomm Snapdragon MSM-8XXXX - что и требовалось доказать. Хак работает одинаково для этих чипов. Возможно есть и другие чипы с которыми он работает

Comment: Хака радиомодуля? Я не перешивал радио модуль, только андроид, на SG2 на MIUI запись голоса собеседника прекрасно работает и да - рут не хочет.

Comment: @Чад хакает сама прога - то есть она использует низкоуровневый доступ к недокументированным фичам радиомодуля

Answer (score 2):

Тоже исследовал этот момент и тоже писал этот кусок кода. Результат был тот же(малый или пустой файл). Потом гуглил много и нашел такой момент: *запись собеседника допустима только в некоторых странах, у гугла даже сервис кажется есть, то бишь регулируется на уровне законодательства, надо понимать*.

Ну и хаки, как уже писали.