# Запись звонков android

Tags: android

как можно записать разговор что бы было слышно обоих?

У меня уже есть проэкт, с записью разговоров но там идет запись именно с микрафона и соответственно не слышно собеседника на записи.

Можете описать примерно как это делается или просто дать ссылку на github библиотеку, которая это уже делает.

Пожалуйста, помогите. Буду рад всем ответам.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запись телефонного разговора в Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/126741/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b2-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запись входящих вызовов была возможна лишь в некоторых странах и на старых версиях андроида. 
Можете поискать решения на гитхабе, как пример 
https://github.com/ViktorDegtyarev/CallRecLib

Не уверен насчет работоспособности, но хотя бы даст какое-то понимание.

Что до новых версий, это возможно только в теории, но нужно будет сначала получить рут на устройстве, и привилегии системного приложения. Плюс скорее всего придется использовать NDK, C/C++. 
В случае если даже у вас всё получится, это приложение вряд ли пройдет проверку Play Market-а.